# Mapping a class and a member function

Tags: c++, templates

Can someone suggest me a way to map a template classes with a set of member functions from another class? Whenever i call one of the function inside a template class, it should call the associated member function of the other class.

Updating with a use-case

```
template<int walktype>
class Walker
{
   Node* node;

    bool walk()
    {
        switch(walktype)
        case 1:
            node->firstwalk();
        case 2:
            node->secondwalk();
        ......

    }
};
```

Please consider the above one as a pseudo-code.
I want the switch-case decision to be taken at the compile time.

Thanks,
Gokul.

Comment: That's called a _class template_, not a template class. And is it delegation you need?

Comment: function pointers inside your template class that you can then assign to the functions inside  your other class

Comment: A use case would be helpful, to see what you want to accomplish.

Comment: sbi,
   Yes it is a class template. Yes i need delegation.  Thanks.

Comment: Tony, I want the association to happen at compile time, not during the run-time.

Comment: The optimizer will eliminate the unreachable the branches, so your code is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it using boost::mpl::map. I need to create a type out of the function and use that type as a template parameter for the class and associate this class with the original class using boost::mpl::map.

Thanks,
Gokul.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want it to be selected in compile time so you can especialize you class template like this:

```
// corresponding to if (walktype != 1) ... condition
template<int>
class Walker
{
    Node* node;

    bool walk()
    {
        node->secondwalk();
    }
};

// corresponding to if (walktype == 1) ... condition
template<>
class Walker<1>
{
    Node* node;
    bool walk()
    {
        node->firstwalk();
    }
};
```

Comment: Sorry, i am misunderstood. i have a set of classes to be mapped against a set of functions. Its just not one specialization

Comment: And if instead of template classes you tried to make overloads for this set of classes? You seem to know which classes your `Walker` class will be used with and this will suffice your compile-time resolution, but I might have misunderstood you again. If you can give us more information, I'll happily edit my answer and try help :)

Comment: I think boost::mpl::map would provide association between two sets of classes, but here i am trying to map a member function against each class. Your answer is fine, but i need to repeat the class definition every time for every template specilaization(lot of code copy/paste). i want to avoid that.